# Select "first level" children in jquery

Tags: jquery

This one is tricky. I haven't ever posted questions here. Always was able to find answers for all questions I have using google, but not for this one.

What I want to accomplish in this sample is to select "first level" descendants for div #main-wrapper that have class `.mb-ctrl.`

"First level" descendants are divs, which closest parent of class `.mb-ctrl` is `#main-wrapper`. In this example "first level" descendants of `#main-wrapper` are `#enclosing1` and `#input2`, but not `#input1`, because it is enclosed in another `.mb-ctrl`.

```html
<div id="main-wrapper" class="mb-ctrl mb-frame">
  <div id="enclosing1" class="mb-ctrl">
    <div id="input1" class="mb-ctrl mb-input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-whatever">
      <div id="input2" class="mb-ctrl mb-input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use this selector `$('#main-wrapper').find('.mb-ctrl')`, I get all `.mb-ctrl` divs. I don't want that.

If I use this selector `$("#main-wrapper").find('.mb-ctrl').not('.mb-ctrl .mb-ctrl')`, I get no divs. I don't want that too.

If I use this selector `$("#main-wrapper").children('.mb-ctrl')`, I get only `#enclosing1`. I don't want that too.

I know that I can use id-s to select what I need, but the structure of my project has varying html with millions of .mb-ctrl-s enclosed in other .mb-ctrl-s and I want to get a universal selector that will work in all cases.

Comment: `$("#main-wrapper").children('.mb-ctrl'), I get only #enclosing1` But, that is the only top level child element that has that class...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector

> Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$("#main-wrapper .mb-ctrl:first-child")
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#main-wrapper .mb-ctrl:first-child").css('color', 'green')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper" class="mb-ctrl mb-frame">
  <div id="enclosing1" class="mb-ctrl">
    enclosing1
    <div id="input1" class="mb-ctrl mb-input">
      input1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-whatever">
      mb-whatever
      <div id="input2" class="mb-ctrl mb-input">
        input2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This selects #enclosing1, #input1 and #input2, but I want to select only #enclosing1 and #input2, because #input1 is a second level descendant

Comment: @OlzhasMurtazin `$("#main-wrapper > .mb-ctrl:first-child")`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#main-wrapper > .mb-ctrl")`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This selects only #enclosing1, but I need to be able to select #enclosing1 and #input2, because #input2 is also a first descendent in that tree branch that has the class .mb-ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this to get "first level" descendants for div "#main-wrapper" that have class ".mb-ctrl".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main-wrapper>.mb-ctrl:first-child");
});
```

here ">" symbol used to get all the immediate child div's of the parent div,
and ":first-child" will filter all the child div's and allowed only first child div.